# Find h in terms of r

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

A sphere and a cylinder have equal volumes. The sphere has a radius 3r. 
The cylinder has radius 2r and height h. 
Find h in terms of r.

I'm only 15, someone walk me through this as simple as possible :)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Sphere_and_Cylinder OR https://www.flocabulary.com/volume-cone-cylinder-sphere/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volume of sphere $= \frac 43 \pi R^3 = \frac 43 \pi (3r)^3$
Volume of cylinder $= \pi R^2 h = \pi(2r)^2h$

These two volumes should be equal so equate them:

$$\frac 43 \pi (3r)^3 = \pi(2r)^2h$$

Now let's solve for $h$ in terms of $r$.

First notice that $(3r)^3 = 3^3r^3 = 27r^3$.  Likewise $(2r)^2 = 2^2r^2 = 4r^2$.  Therefore

$$\frac 43 \pi (3r)^3 = \pi(2r)^2h \\ \implies \frac 43 \pi \color{red}{(27r^3)} = \pi\color{red}{(4r^2)}h \\ \implies \frac 43 \color{red}{(27r^3)}\pi  = \color{red}{(4r^2)}\pi h \\ \implies \color{blue}{\frac{4\cdot 27}{3}}r^3\pi = 4r^2\pi h$$

Now before we go on, notice that there is a $4r^2\pi$ on both sides.  So let's divide both sides by $4r^2\pi$:

$$\require{cancel}\frac{4\cdot 27}{3}r^3\pi = 4r^2\pi h \\ \implies \frac {27}{3}\color{blue}{(4r^2\pi)}r = \color{blue}{(4r^2\pi)} h \\ \implies \frac{\frac {27}{3}\cancel{\color{blue}{(4r^2\pi)}}r}{\cancel{\color{blue}{(4r^2\pi)}}} = \frac{\cancel{\color{blue}{(4r^2\pi)}} h}{\cancel{\color{blue}{(4r^2\pi)}}} \\ \implies \frac {27}{3}r=h \\ \implies 9r=h$$

So your answer is $\require{enclose}\enclose{box} {h=9r}$.  This is an expression for $h$ in terms of $r$.

Comment: So the general formulae for the volume of a cylinder is 4/3piR^3

Comment: [That's correct](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.01/rahul1.html).

Comment: How would I caculate this without a calculator as I assume 4÷3*3.14*2^3?

Comment: The $\pi$ actually cancels on both sides so you don't need to make the approximation $\pi \approx 3.14$.  But if you *do* want the volume for some reason, then yes, that's the approximation you'd have to make.

Comment: Oh, hold up.  Your first comment is incorrect.  The volume of a cylinder is $\pi R^2 h$.  The volume of a *sphere* is $\frac 43 \pi R^3$.  Sorry -- I didn't read it closely enough.  To remember the volume of a cylinder just recall that if an object has a constant cross section (in this case all of the cross sections of a cylinder are circles of radius $R$), then the object's volume is just "base $\times$ height".

Comment: So what formulae would I use to calculate h,  im so lost

Comment: Can you simplify $\frac 43 \pi (3r)^3 = \pi(2r)^2h$?  Because that's all you're asked for.  So you won't get a number for $h$ -- you'll just get $h=$ something involving $r$.

Comment: I guess you can simplify it but I don't know how :'(

Comment: OK.  I'll edit it into the question.  These are skills you need to learn though or you're going to be very sad come test time.

Comment: I've been sat here trying to learn everything for my mocks,  but some stuff is so hard. Seeing as my desired career is math based I gotta get good.  Thanks by they way

Comment: You saved my good grade thank you

Answer (score 1):

So $\frac{4}{3}\pi (3r)^3 = h\pi(2r)^2 \implies \pi36r^3 = h\pi4r^2 \implies 9r = h$.